# How to limit the number of data to be uploaded to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

How can I limit the number of data to be uploaded to Elasticsearch? My old laptop cannot process a huge dataset like the one I'm using.

I have used the following code to 'limit' the data to be uploaded

```py
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
import csv
import itertools

with open('my_data.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 1000): #limitation of data
        helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='movie-plots', doc_type=None)
```

But this is apparently not working; when I check with 'POST movie-plots/_count', it returns the initial size of the entire dataset.

I am completely new to Elasticsearch so sorry if this is a novice question. I am using Python client (in Jupyter notebook) in order to use Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `islice` on `reader` ... but then you are passing all of `reader` to `helpers.bulk` anyway.

Not in a place where I can test; but try removing the `for` loop and just passing the `islice` to `helpers.bulk` directly:

```py
with open('my_data.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, itertools.islice(reader, 1000), index='movie-plots', doc_type=None)
```

Comment: thank you very much! does that take the first 1000?

Comment: Yup, that's what `islice` does.